# Getting the Server CPU Usage on Windows using PHP?

Tags: php, windows-server-2012-r2

I've tried several lines of codes to get CPU Usage but they all return NULL or Empty Value just 0% even if the real CPU usage is 16%.

Here are the methods I've tried:

1. using the COM class. (example below)

   `$wmi = new COM("Winmgmts://");
   $result = $wmi->execquery("SELECT LoadPercentage FROM Win32_Processor");`
2. using exec in PHP

   `exec(typeperf -sc 1 \"processor(_Total)\% Processor Time\");
   exec("wmic cpu get LoadPercentage /Value", $lines);`

I'm using Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Just tried following code on Win 2012 machine and it works like a charm: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-getloadavg.php#107243

Comment: @rndus2r I've tried this, it somehow returned 0% as a result even though the CPU Usage from Task Manager is between 5% to 11% at time of testing.

Comment: What's your system locale?

Comment: @mdus2r sorry for late reply, I was out of town. My system locale is English (United States)